# Internal compiler error even on blank project with Xcode 9

Tags: compiler-errors, xcode9

After trying couple of simple commands and receiving Build Failed error,
I tried a simple blank slate and still got the same error.

I tried cleaning up, re-installing Xcode 9, Restart System...none worked.

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: [Try moving your Xcode.app into your root `/Application` folder](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/49116) and see if that solves your issue.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann thank you Michael, I did move Xcode, no luck.